# MVC 4 ConnectionString on my godaddy hosting Error 166

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I am testing a website, mvc 4 website; I am learning actually MVC.

I have published the website to my personal hosting, on my computers works good, but once is on my hosting I have an error, here are the connection string first: (I am using northwind to practice)

```
 <add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.NorthWindModel.csdl|res://*/Models.NorthWindModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.NorthWindModel.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;
     data source=**************.db.********.hostedresource.com;;
     initial catalog=**********;
     User ID=******;         
     MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
     App=EntityFramework&quot;
     Password='********';
     integrated security=True;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and here is the error:

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 166. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 166.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 166.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5078242
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +132
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +98
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +118
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +81
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +78
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +32
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +131
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +281
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +56
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +40
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   MvcApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Index() +21
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass39.b_*33() +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4f.b_*49() +240
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass37.b_*36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClass1d.b_*18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b_*3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClass8.b_*3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

So, what in the world is happening? I have tried many different connectionStrings without success.

Thanks

Comment: Two adjacent ;; on position 166?

Comment: Wiktor, I cannot believe that my problem was that simple, also I removed integrated security=True; but the main problem was the double ;
 Make a post to give you as the right answer!

Comment: Will post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two adjacent ;; at position 166.

Comment: you got it!!! ;) 
that was the problem, and when it was sold I just deleted the integrated security=True; bc I had password and login.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the information in these GoDaddy articles:

[Locating Your Database Connection Strings](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3323/locating-your-database-connection-strings)

[Connecting to a SQL Server Database Using ASP.NET 3.5](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/689/connecting-to-a-sql-server-database-using-aspnet-35) (I realise you're using asp.net mvc 4 but maybe this will help)

If you need more help you should contact GoDaddy as this is too specific/localised for a StackOverflow question

Comment: Hi Dean, it was the double ;. I cannot believe that I never saw it!!! haha, well, thanks for your answer also!

Comment: No worries, glad you've got it working. I'll edit my answer to remove Wiktor Zychla's bit